# $\int_{[-a,a]} h(x) = \int_{[-a,a]} h(-x) ?$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, periodic-functions

Suppose $h$ is a $2a$-periodic function ($a > 0)$ that is integrable on $[-a,a]$, is it true that $\int_{[-a,a]} h(x) = \int_{[-a,a]} h(-x) ?$

I'm currently stuck and not sure what to do. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: What's the relevance of the fact that $h$ is periodic with period $2a$ when you are integrating it over an interval whose length is $2a$?

Comment: What do you get when you make the change of variable $x \mapsto -x$ to the integral on the left-hand side of your equation?

Comment: Is there any approach that does not use the change of variable? I have not been exposed to that yet.

Comment: @vitamin d I'm currently taking a class on measure theory and we have not yet proved any change of variable theorem for lebesgue integral, therefore, I'm not allowed to use it. This is one of the small lemma that I thought of, which would help me to solve my current problem. Of course I know how to perform a change of variable, but that would make this trivial. Not sure why I'm getting attacked here.

Comment: @S10000 Please don't think you were getting attacked :). My comment was "@S10000 If you don't know how to perform a change of variable, consider to learn that first before asking further question about integrals." (didn't mean to harm anyone. )

Answer (score 4):

Sub in the last integral:
$$\int_{[-a,a]} h(-x)=-\int_{[a,-a]} h(x)=\int_{[-a,a]} h(x)$$